# Different modem and router IP addresses

Tags: networking, ip, router, modem

I'll try to explain best I can.

My ISP gave me modem, that modem only has 1 WAN output (to connect to my router). I have TP Link router with WAN input and 4 LAN outputs. Basic connection is : straight LAN cable, from modem WAN output to router WAN input.

Router LAN settings are :

IP : 192.168.1.1

Subnet Mask : 255.255.255.0

DHCP Server is disabled on modem, but enabled on TP Link router, I have already setup DHCP to give my home PCs certain IP addresses.

Thing is, my modem has IP : 192.168.100.1

If I am not wrong they should not be able to communicate each other, because there is a different subnet mask on 192.168.100.1

How am I able to see my modem via router?

And off course how setup my network properly?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT : I do have occasional packet loss, is it possible to have that due to bad network configuration?

Comment: *"I'll try to explain best I can."* -- You need to do better than that.  What is the actual problem?  *"How am I able to see my modem via router?"*  --  What does *"see"* mean?  Does this mean that your PCs cannot connect to the Internet?  Or does it mean that your PCs cannot log into the modem's web server?

Comment: "How am I able to see my modem via router?" - How am I able to access web UI of modem (192.168.100.1) on my PC that is running on 192.168.1.100 via TP Link router (192.168.1.1).

I'm connected but I have occasional packet loss.

Comment: What is the purpose of the modem and the TP Link router in your setup?

Comment: Have you manually set the WAN IP address on your router to also be in the 192.168.100.0 (/24?) network? If not, it's likely that your modem is automatically assigned your router WAN interface an IP address in that network via DHCP. Your router now has an interface in two networks and can route between them.

Comment: If your router is 192.168.1.1/24, and your modem is 192.168.100.1/24, there should not be any issue. Connect the modem WAN output to the WAN input on the router. Any traffic that isn't managed by your router, i.e., anything other than 192.168.1.0/24, will be sent out its default gateway to the modem. You can manage your modem the same way as when it is plugged directly into your computer.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Because ISP gave me modem so I could have connection to internet, and I need more than one port.


MarkoPolo I did not set that.


varlogtim So my network is configured correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Better to enable DHCP in the modem and disable it in your TP Link router.

First set up TP-Link with:

- Static LAN IP in the same network as the modem, (192.168.1.254 mask 255.255.255.0) for example.
- Disable DHCP
- Enable WiFi if you have it.

To do this connect directly to it in isolation using http://192.168.100.1, then you should be able to connect to it with http://192.168.1.254

Then connect the modem to the TP-Link in any of the LAN outputs and you are done.

Anything you then connect to the TP-Link, via WiFi or LAN will get its IP from the modem because it is and should be the only DHCP server in the network, and everything will be able to connect to the Internet without extra NAT.

You should be able to manage the modem using http://192.168.1.1 and the TP-Link with http://192.168.1.254. One network, easy.

Comment: Thing is, my TP Link has A LOT of settings, and my modem doesn't have any... So I would like to stay DHCP on TP Link.

Comment: also, i need all 4 ports from my LAN

Answer (score 0):

I know everyone is over this question by now, but I couldn't help myself.
First, your explanation was perfect. We all know what "see" means in networking, there's no need for further explanation.
Second, your setup is most likely correct, the router is a much better option to be your DHCP server and anything else your network requires. Your modem should be used for that purpose only if possible, a modem.
Third, the only way for devices to talk between subnets is to have a router involved. The router does exactly that, it routes traffic between different subnets. This is why you can see your modem from your router.
I'm going to stop there since this post is so outdated. Thank you for posting. I'm sorry you were met with such aggression initially.